# Partial completions in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is it possible to have partial completions in Xcode? By that I mean if we were calling a method on a string

eg.

```
[string <some method here method>]
```

on XCode, currently if you type

`[string`

and hit escape, you'll see suggestions for methods you can call on the object. If I wanted to find the method which checks equality `isEqualToString`, I only get the suggestion if I start typing `isE...`, but is there a way code completion will still give `isEqualToString` as a suggestion if I type "equal" ie. it matches against any part of a method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but there is no way, there aren't really any ways to change the way Xcode handles the code completion, all you can do is turn it on or off. Your best bet may be a feature request to Apple.